# Does a scaffold coupler connecting metal steel tube to a round one, exist?

Tags: connectors

I am looking for a seamless way to connect a steel rectangular tube to a round one. The most straightforward solution which comes to mind, would be a scaffold coupler, but does such a type exist?

What I have discovered so far is the ladder scaffold coupler:

[image]

but it does not seem to be fitting a 5cmx5cm tube.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending what it is for, welding the proper size square to round tube to make a coupling is probably the fastest or maybe a big hammer to make the square fit over the round and a drill.

Comment: Welding would not be seamless, though... as well as hammering and drilling.

Comment: "seamless way to join"  what does that even mean?

Comment: @ Jasen - well, no drilling, no welding. Just the way scaffold couplers work.